# Something wrong with nginx and port 80

Tags: nginx

I've got an application at `192.168.101.120:8080`. Now I want to run it throug nginx on port `80`. Look at the `nginx.conf`:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;



server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myserver.com;   

        location / {
            root /some/public/folder;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;            
            proxy_pass http://192.168.101.120:8080;
        }
    }



}
```

But port `80` shows me default nginx page. I can change `listen 80;` to `listen 8081;` and everything will be fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a default.conf or something similar that nginx is loading.

Try this

```
grep -r 80 /etc/nginx/*
```

That might give you some hints if I'm correct.

Comment: Yes, I've got it. `listen  80 default_server;`. Should I delete that?

Comment: look in the file.. if it looks like the default server {} entry then you are ok to delete it. You might just want to mv it to /tmp just in case you'd want it back.. or remove the default_server and add it to your server {}

Answer (score 2):

Your `server_name` definition doesn't match the URL you are using, therefore you are getting the wrong virtual host. Remember, `http://www.myserver.com` does not work when `server_name` is `mysserver.com`.

Comment: Presumably the second 's' in your `mysserver.com` example is a typo?